# Select inter-dependant data in redux store with reselect createSelector

Tags: redux, react-redux, reselect

So, I am using [redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#implementing-container-components), and [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) tool `createSelector` to memoize my selectors in `mapStateToProps`, and it is great.

Now, I have some normalized data in my store, and a container that needs inter-dependant data from the store.

I am doing this, for the moment, and it works:

```js
const getItemId = props => parseInt(props.match.params.itemId, 10)

const containerSelector = createSelector(getItemId, itemId =>
  createSelector(
    [getUser, getItem(itemId)],
    (user, item) =>
      createSelector(
        [
          getFoo(item.fooId),
          getBar(item.barId)
        ],
        (foo, bar) => ({ user, item, foo, bar })
      )
  )
)

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) =>
  containerSelector(ownProps)(state)(state)

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Container)
```

**Question: is there a better way to do this?**

1. more readable?
2. Better practice?
3. More performant? (is this performant?)

**Edit:**

**Thanks to Tho Vu answer, I could made it simpler and memoized, like this:**

```
import { getUser, getItemById, getFooById } from 'selectors'

// Note: getStuffById are selector factories like: 
//   const getStuffById = id => state => state.stuff.objects[id] 

const itemIdSelector = (_, props) => parseInt(props.match.params.itemId, 10)

const itemSelector = (state, props) => {
   const itemId = itemIdSelector(state, props)
   return getItemById(itemId)(state)
}

const fooSelector = (state, props) => {
   const item = itemSelector(state, props)
   return item ? getFooById(item.fooId)(state) : null
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({ 
  user: getUser, 
  itemId: itemIdSelector, 
  item: itemSelector,
  foo: fooSelector
})
```

But I am still mixed about it? Or maybe it is fine already?

Comment: I'm quite confused by `getItemById` and `getFooById` which seems to be selector factories (functions which return a new, partially configured selector), used like plain selector. If it's the case, there would be still room for improvement.

Comment: Yes, that's right, selector factories based on object `id` - added an explanatory comment in example code.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of `reselect`:

> When a selector is connected to a component with connect, the
>   component props are passed as the second argument to the selector

So the first `createSelector` layer used for getting `itemId` is actually unnecessary, which you can replace with:

```
const getItem = (state, props) => {
   const itemId = parseInt(props.match.params.itemId, 10)
   return getItem(itemId)
}
```

Secondly, `createSelector` has following attribute:

> Selectors created with createSelector have a cache size of 1. This
>   means they always recalculate when the value of an input-selector
>   changes, as a selector only stores the preceding value of each
>   input-selector.

Which means your custom selector will recalculate with every changes of `user`, `itemId`, `item`, `foo`, `bar`. It is hard to say about the rest of input-selectors, but I don't see any relationship between `user` and the others. Thus you should create a separate selector for only `user`.

Also, the purpose of `createSelector` is to create a selector with retainable memoization, so nesting them the way you do will cause inside selector to be recreated every time outer ones recalculate.

What I normally do is flatten them like this:

```
const getItem = (state, props) => {
   const itemId = parseInt(props.match.params.itemId, 10)
   return getItem(itemId)
}

const userSelector = createSelector(getUser, user => user)
const itemSelector = createSelector(getItem, item => item)
```

`foo` and `bar` are more difficult, because in your code, the selectors look for changes in `item`, `item.fooId` and `foo` too recalculate. We still need to nest the selectors, but separation of `foo` and `bar` is required:

```
const fooFromItemSelector = createSelector(itemSelector, item => getFoo(item.fooId))
const fooSelector = createSelector(fooFromItemSelector, foo => foo)
```

and same goes for `bar`.

Lastly, you will want to group them together to create `containerSelector`:

```
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect'

const containerSelector = createStructuredSelector({
    user: userSelector,
    item: itemSelector,
    foo: fooSelector,
    bar: barSelector
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! Makes total sense. I had an issue with some mixed-up getters/selectors that had the wrong signature `getStuff = id => state => state.stuff[id]` and which led me to the confusion on how to use `createSelector`. I inverted and renamed to `getStuffSelector = state => id => state.stuff[id]` so I can use then in `createSelector` in a way that is very close to your answer. What do you think?

Comment: @Pandaiolo That should be fine I believe.

Comment: Ok so I think the identity pattern with `const itemSelector = createSelector(getItem, item => item)` is not working. This basically returns *selector of a selector*, because `getItem` does not returns data, but a selector. I managed to make it work by returning `getItem(itemId)(state)` instead, but then using `itemSelector` is useless, as you can just use `getItem` in `createStructuredSelector` and it will be memoized. Thoughts?

Comment: *(and solution in my above comment did not work either because it memoized the selector function, that never changes, whatever underlying value that it is getting later on)*